# Removing active animations from a DependencyProperty in WinRT

Tags: animation, windows-runtime, dependency-properties

When you have an animated DependencyProperty, how do you remove all active animations? In WPF you could...

```
myDependencyObject.BeginAnimation(<propery path>, null);
```

... and that would remove all animations. Is there an equivalent in WinRT (aka Windows Store Apps)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution I don't like: keep track of the storyboard to which the animation belongs and manually Stop() it when you want to replace it :/. 
Hope this helps somebody.

Edit-
The reason this seems like a poor solution is that it requires the thing that starts the new animation to have some sort of connection to the thing that started the old animation. Ideally the animation target would be affected by different parts of the system at different times and those parts that do the animating would be completely decoupled.